# Read a single number from a file in Perl

Tags: perl

How to read a PID number from a file in a better way?

A file named `pid` contains the current process's PID or a 0;

I want to read it from the file in a variable and I came with the longest possible solution:

```
open my $fh, '<', 'pid';
my $line = <$fh>;
close $fh;

chomp $line;
my $pid = 0+ $line;

say $pid;
```

Is there a more elegant solution?

Comment: Why do you need the `0+`, if the file contains the PID or 0?

Comment: I need to have it in the $pid variable anyway from $line. Sure casting to number in Perl doesn't make sense.

Comment: @MiroslavPopov: *I need to have it in the `$pid` variable anyway from `$line`* Or you could read it directly into `$pid`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The common way without modules would be:

```
open my $fh, '<', 'pid' or die $!;
chomp( my $pid = <$fh> );
```

No need to close the filehandle, it will be closed when it runs out of scope. Checking the return value of open, though, is not optional.

Answer (score 2):

I like [Path::Tiny](https://metacpan.org/pod/Path::Tiny) for doing things like this.

```
use Path::Tiny;

chomp(my $pid = path('pid')->slurp);
```

Or

```
use Path::Tiny;

my ($pid) = path('pid')->lines({ chomp => 1, count => 1 });
```

I'm not sure why you want to force the file to be a number. Do you not trust the contents of the file?

Comment: +1 for `chomp( my $pid = ... )`. I didn't know how to shorten that. First thought `my $pid = chomp <$fh>;`, but it returns the count of chomps:)))